# use 1 view for many pictures

Tags: listview, android-intent, textview, imageview

i have an listview with 1 pic in every row. after clicking on such a childrow i wanna get detailed information of the childrow entry. for that i want to have a new intent which has an imageView that displays exactly the same pic i used before in the listview, together with a special text.

all in all i want to have only 1 intent which displays different entries depending on which childrow of the listview the user clicked.

it would be nice if you could give me a sample code because i am new in android programming and programming at all and not familiar with all these classes.

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

override the following method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        //get the item clicked here and pass it to the intent you are starting
}
```

In the called activity retrieve the value and assign it to the imageview. if you are not able to get this post what you have done i will modify the code

Comment: i am not able to do it sry -.- pls modify it by time .. thx:)